# Google's global quick search widget missing in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was unable to find the google's search widget on the home screen
neither on the the list of available widgets.If i click menu from the
home screen and if i press search nothing happens.

I could neither find an option called "Search" in settings page from
where i could enable my application in searchable items.The issue is
we have enabled Global search for our application and previously if
used to show search results from my application if i search here.

I tested this in a stimulator and i am yet to test it on a device.

Has it been removed in 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Android SDK 2.2 which was later confirmed by a Google employee in a separate post

[Android 2.2 AVD: no Quick Search Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912887/android-2-2-avd-no-quick-search-box)

Comment: when i use search option in my application,i'm getting NumberFormat exception,i too using android-2.2 avd,whether is'y the probelm in Android SDK2.2 or something else the same function is working in 2.1 1nd others