# Android 2.2 AVD: no Quick Search Box?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have recently updated my Android SDK to include support for Android 2.2 (API level 8). The app that I'm building integrates with the Quick Search Box (QSB) home screen widget, which I can't seem to find in this version (using both vanilla 2.2 and the Google APIs version). I was kind of excited when they announced that they have improved its functionality, but it seems there's no way for me to observe it.

Is this normal? Are others experiencing the same issue? Or is this somehow related to my setup (running Archlinux and installed the Android SDK from the repositories).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ Google's global quick search widget missing in Android 2.2 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882859/googles-global-quick-search-widget-missing-in-android-2-2)

Comment: @Dave you are right. I searched before asking, but couldn't find that one. At least I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and we are working on it internally.

Comment: An actual Android engineer! Heh, thanks for answering. Marked your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seem's like a bug in Android Launcher application, since no search widget (which is not actually a app widget) and `Menu -> Search` does nothing

Comment: It is definitely not a bug in the Launcher :)