# android how to place a Quick Search Box in application

Tags: android

I want to develop an app which connect with the server and a quick search box should be there which should work as Google search.
How can I do that? Please give me a sample example.
One more question, is 2.2 supporting QSB?

Comment: No it dosn't support QSB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912887/android-2-2-avd-no-quick-search-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it searcheble

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

Add QSB To your app **BUT 2.2 Dosen't Support is Yet**

http://shapingclouds.com/2009/10/19/how-add-searchmanager-quick-search-to-your-android-application/

[Further info](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make searcheble to main activity? If yes what should I write?

Comment: what do you mean by _make searcheble to main activity ?_