# How to log search requests on Android

Tags: android, search, logging, android-intent, contentobserver

I am trying to log the search requests on android devices. How can i take the history of quick search box(QSB). Is there any way to take the text using ContentObserver or BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: did you try to search solution on google.??

Comment: yes but i fail to find any clue

Comment: see here..,io think here you will get solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339449/android-how-to-place-a-quick-search-box-in-application

Comment: thanks!,but the solution described here  implements a way to get notification : how can i get the actual content?