# How would i down-sample a .wav file then reconstruct it using nyquist? - in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, resampling

This is all done in MATLAB 2010

My objective is to show the results of: undersampling, nyquist rate/ oversampling

First i need to downsample the .wav file to get an incomplete/ or impartial data stream that i can then reconstuct.

Heres the flow chart of what im going to be doing So the flow is analog signal -> sampling analog filter -> ADC -> resample down -> resample up -> DAC -> reconstruction analog filter

what needs to be achieved:

> F= Frequency
>
> F(Hz=1/s) E.x. 100Hz = 1000 (Cyc/sec)
>   F(s)= 1/(2f)
>
> Example problem: 1000 hz = Highest
>   frequency 1/2(1000hz) = 1/2000 =
>   5x10(-3) sec/cyc or a sampling rate of
>   5ms

This is my first signal processing project using matlab.

what i have so far.

```
% Fs = frequency sampled (44100hz or the sampling frequency of a cd)

[test,fs]=wavread('test.wav'); % loads the .wav file
left=test(:,1);

% Plot of the .wav signal time vs. strength

time=(1/44100)*length(left);
t=linspace(0,time,length(left));
plot(t,left)
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('relative signal strength')

**%this is were i would need to sample it at the different frequecys (both above and below and at) nyquist frequency.*I think.***

soundsc(left,fs) % shows the resaultant audio file , which is the same as original ( only at or above nyquist frequency however)
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it better, and how to do the sampling at verious frequencies?

heres the .wav file http://www.4shared.com/audio/11xvNmkd/piano.html

EDIT:

```
%Play decimated file ( soundsc(y,fs) ) 
%Play Original file ( soundsc(play,fs ) )
%Play reconstucted File ( soundsc(final,fs) )

[piano,fs]=wavread('piano.wav'); % loads piano
play=piano(:,1); % Renames the file as "play"

t = linspace(0,time,length(play));          % Time vector
x = play;
y = decimate(x,25);

stem(x(1:30)), axis([0 30 -2 2])   % Original signal
title('Original Signal')
figure
stem(y(1:30))                        % Decimated signal
title('Decimated Signal')

%changes the sampling rate

fs1 = fs/2;
fs2 = fs/3;
fs3 = fs/4;
fs4 = fs*2;
fs5 = fs*3;
fs6 = fs*4;

wavwrite(y,fs/25,'PianoDecimation');


%------------------------------------------------------------------

%Downsampled version of piano is now upsampled to the original
[PianoDecimation,fs]=wavread('PianoDecimation.wav'); % loads piano
play2=PianoDecimation(:,1); % Renames the file as "play

%upsampling
UpSampleRatio = 2;  % 2*fs = nyquist rate sampling
play2Up=zeros(length(PianoDecimation)*UpSampleRatio, 1);
play2Up(1:UpSampleRatio:end) = play2; % fill in every N'th sample

%low pass filter

ResampFilt = firpm(44, [0 0.39625 0.60938 1], [1 1 0 0]);


fsUp = (fs*UpSampleRatio)*1;
wavwrite(play2Up,fsUp,'PianoUpsampled');

%Plot2
%data vs time plot
time=(1/44100)*length(play2);
t=linspace(0,time,length(play2));
stem(t,play2)
title('Upsampled graph of piano')
xlabel('time(sec)');
ylabel('relative signal strength')



[PianoUpsampled,fs]=wavread('PianoUpsampled.wav'); % loads piano
final=PianoUpsampled(:,1); % Renames the file as "play"


%-------------------------------------------------------------
%resampleing
[piano,fs]=wavread('piano.wav'); % loads piano
x=piano(:,1); % Renames the file as "play"
m = resample(x,3,2);
```

Original:
http://www.4shared.com/audio/11xvNmkd/piano.html

New:
http://www.4shared.com/audio/nTRBNSld/PianoUs.html

Comment: what do you mean, from my previous questions ive asked about nyquist sampling using a msp430 micro controller, this has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It means you click the green checkmark on an answer for one of your previous questions, as done [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882859/googles-global-quick-search-widget-missing-in-android-2-2). It awards the author extra points and allows future users & searchers to see which answer was most helpful.

Comment: Most helpful for my question about the msp430 board yea. . .

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is change sample rates by an integer factor. *Downsampling* consists of running the data through a low-pass filter followed by discarding samples, while *upsampling* consists of inserting samples then running the data through a low pass filter (also known as a reconstruction filter or interpolating filter).  Aliasing occurs when the filtering steps are skipped or poorly done.  So, to show the effect of aliasing, I suggest you simply discard or insert samples as required, then create a new WAV file at the new sample rate.  To discard samples, you can do:

```
DownSampleRatio = 2;
%# Normally apply a low pass filter here
leftDown = left(1:DownSampleRatio:end); %# extract every N'th sample
fsDown = fs/DownSampleRatio;
wavwrite(leftDown, fsDown, filename);
```

To create samples you can do:

```
UpSampleRatio = 2;
leftUp = zeros(length(left)*UpSampleRatio, 1);
leftUp(1:UpSampleRatio:end) = left; %# fill in every N'th sample
%# Normally apply a low pass filter here
fsUp = fs*UpSampleRatio;
wavwrite(leftUp, fsUp, filename);
```

You can just play back the written WAV files to hear the effects.

As an aside, you asked for improvements to your code - I prefer to initialize the `t` vector as `t = (0:(length(left)-1))/fs;`.

Comment: Shouldnt they sound the same once this is done, when i tried it , it doesn't sound the same at all.

Comment: Both processes introduce aliasing, so no, they shouldn't sound the same.  You would have to (a) ensure that the original signal didn't have energy above fsDown/2 and (b) include the low-pass filtering steps I mentioned above for them to sound the same.

Comment: yea i added a low pass filter, ill edit the code uptop so you can see it.

Comment: First, that low pass filter is weak.  You need to make sure it attenuates everything above fsDown/2.  Second, in upsampling, you need to apply it to the upsampled data.

Comment: The low pass filter? its applied to both, but what would a better low lass filter be instead of the current one?  and instead of downsampling decimation would be better as Clifford said. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/decimate.html i need to find a way to implement it to a audio file rather then a sine wave.

Comment: 1. Design a low-pass filter with cutoff at pi/2.  In DSP, the frequency band is usually normalized to pi.  Fs = 2pi, so then FUseful, or FNyquist, is pi (Fs/2).  When you decimate by 2, your new Fs will be pi, and your new FUseful will be pi/2.  So you need to have filtered all the energy above pi/2 before downsampling.  2. In the upsampling code, apply the filter to `play2Up`, not `play2`.  3. Decimation is the name given to low-pass filtering plus downsampling.  The upsampling equivalent is usually called interpolation.

Comment: I understand what you saying, it makes perfect sense, but i'm kinda in a "fish out of water" situation. This is my DSP related code. So, in this instance how would i design the low pass filter? and it would be the same for both down and up sampling?

Comment: Try `ResampFilt = firpm(44, [0 0.39625 0.60938 1], [1 1 0 0]);`  I highly highly recommend you use the `filter` function to apply the filter to your data.  It's the same coefficients for both down and up.

Comment: so use that in place of my current low pass filter?

Comment: Yes. Your current LPF has very little attenuation so you'll get lots of aliasing.

Comment: well when i did this, it worked, although it wounded like it was playing at 2x speed, but its only the higher frequency's that come through. this is the upsampled version of the .wav file http://www.4shared.com/audio/nTRBNSld/PianoUs.html

Comment: Did you specify the new sampling rate when you played back the data?

Comment: Ill update the code in my original post and add the original and up sampled version of the wave file so you can see whats going on.

Comment: im also getting a Warning: Data clipped during write to file:PianoUs 
> In wavwrite>PCM_Quantize at 287
  In wavwrite>write_wavedat at 309
  In wavwrite at 138
  In Upsamling at 25

Comment: You realize you're not actually applying the low pass filter? Try typing in `help firpm` and `help filter` at the MATLAB prompt.

Comment: but somehow it actually works better form applying the low pass filter.

Comment: Um, except for the whole sounding like a chipmunk thing.  By the way, the resampling filter I suggested is only appropriate for a resampling ratio of 2.

Comment: At a down sample ratio of 2 , it sounds too close to the original by means of no distinct change in the 2 samples, so if you were to re write to wrong parts of the filtering system in place now, what would you say?

Comment: Now I'm not sure what your goal is.  Traditionally, the point of downsampling and upsampling is to change the sample rate while introducing as little distortion as possible.  When downsampling, the result is supposed to sound like the original, except for missing high frequencies.  When upsampling, the result should sound exactly like the original.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: well im trying to take a complete soundclip and decimate it ( http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/decimate.html ), this is to simulate an impartial audio clip, then i want to resample it at 2x+ the highest frequency (Nyquist, over-undersampling) to reconstruct the original audio clip. With as little distortion as possible. This is to observe the role of nyquist rate sampling and compare it to undersampling.

Comment: What do you mean by impartial?

Comment: like ever other point in the data stream from the audio clip is taken out, ( accomplished by decimating it). I'm just trying to simulate a "corrupted" file for example data lost in transmission of the audio clip, i dont really know how to explain it. resamples the filtered data by selecting every nth point.

Comment: To decimate:     t = 0:.00025:1;                      % Time vector
x = sin(2*pi*30*t) + sin(2*pi*60*t);
y = decimate(x,4);

stem(x(1:120)), axis([0 120 -2 2])   % Original signal
title('Original Signal')
figure
stem(y(1:30))                        % Decimated signal
title('Decimated Signal')

Comment: You know that MATLAB's `decimate` function low pass filters the data internally right?  So if you're trying to simulate corruption due to data loss, I understand why you're not applying the low pass filter when downsampling.  But it's a basic tenet of DSP that once you have introduced aliasing into a data stream, it's impossible to recover the original data.  So what you're trying to do (if I understand you correctly) is not possible.

Comment: So what would you recommend doing to still present a good experiment? That is similar to this.

Comment: I think you've got a good experiment.  You've shown that the audio file gets effed when you dowsample without low-pass filtering.  That's what you wanted to show.

Comment: What else do you think i could to expand on this? and could i re write this for a microcontroller do you think?

Comment: For microcontroller, do you mean using a real ADC?  Most baseband ADCs these days are delta-sigma, and thus have anti-aliasing filters built in.  So you'll have to sample at a high rate, then replace samples with zeros in the uC, then output to the DAC.  So sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: just a question, the more i decimate the signal the worse the upsampled file will sound?

Comment: Generally that should be the case.

Comment: WHat type of audio signal would be best to start with to optimize the results?

Comment: Im thinking of showing the results with first a sine wave then doing the music track so its more clear.

Comment: Try with a sine wave that slowly changes in pitch. The aliasing frequencies introduced by poor downsampling will rise if the sine wave falls in pitch, and will fall if the source sine wave rises in pitch.

Answer (score 0):

The DSP technique you need is called [decimation](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/decimation).

Comment: yea, i was reading online and i saw this. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/decimate.html . Im trying to figure out how to implement it with a audio file instead of a sine wave. So, y=decimate(x,r) were x = audio file and r is the factor at which its decimated?

Comment: @Andrew: Their example data is not a sine wave, it is the sum of two sine waves, and audio signal is (like any other signal) the sum of a number of sine waves of differing amplitude, frequency and phase.  There is no difference between using a variable representing an audio stream and one mathematically generated.  You simply use your audio sample variable in place of their *x* variable.  Matlab has a function for reading a WAV file into such a variable.